# Which chapter of the manga does Season 3 of Dr Stone anime starts?

Tags: dr.stone

Season 3 of the Dr Stone manga started, and I'm trying to spoil myself with details of the manga by starting to read the next chapter of the last anime episode they've shown. So I wanted to know where to read the manga season 3 of the anime follows.

Which chapter of the manga does Season 3 of Dr Stone anime starts?

Answer (score 0):

The beginning of Dr. Stone Season 3 shows them building something and the same frame exists in Chapter 84.